# Take numbers from a cell (Google sheets)

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I would like to know if there is a way to do the following: Let's say I have this text in a cell:

```
{ "Hi": 1111111 "how": 2222222 "are": 3333333 "you": 4444444 "?": 5555555 }
```

Now, I need to have a cell that always gives me the number after "how"? No matter what the rest of the input is. Meaning, if I change the cell to look like this.

```
{ XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX"how": 3333333 }
```

The result should be `3333333`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"how\D+(\d+)")
```